# How to find databricks cluster owner has permission for secrets?

Tags: databricks

i am facing below error while executing databricks notebook.

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT(CLIENT_ERROR): databricks_error_message:Cannot fetch secrets referred in the Spark configuration. Please check that the secrets exists and the cluster's owner has the read permission.
```

i know below cmd will give permission details for the user but i don't know how to get cluster's owner details. and the cluster creator has already access to the cluster.

```
>>databricks secrets get-acl --scope scope_name --principal username
```

how to check the databricks cluster's owner details and resolve this issue?

i have granted access to cluster created but still facing same error.

Comment: The issue is with spark configuration, after changing spark - the job was using both hive and glue configs. after removing hive configs the issue fixed.